# How can I validate a date in a form in Phalcon?

Tags: date, datepicker, mariadb, phalcon, volt

I build a webpage using the framework Phalcon. I have a form asking for a text, an integer and a date. I'm using datepicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to get the date. When I make the insertion in the database this date is not inserted, only the text and the int. 
I think it is problem of the format of the date, so I want to validate it. 
I can validate the presence of data in the text fields but I don't find any "validator" to validate it is a date.

This is my form class:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Forms\Form;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Date;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Password;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;

class NuevakeywordForm extends Form{

public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null){
    // Trackeable
    $trackeable = new Text('trackeable');
    $trackeable->setLabel('Palabra Clave');
    $trackeable->setFilters(array('striptags', 'string'));
    $trackeable->addValidators(array(
        new PresenceOf(array(
            'message' => 'Palabra clave requerida'
            ))
        ));
    $this->add($trackeable);

    // IdCliente
    $idcliente = new Text('idcliente');
    $idcliente->setLabel('idcliente');
    $idcliente->addValidators(array(
        new PresenceOf(array(
            'message' => 'IdCliente is required'
            ))
        ));
    $this->add($idcliente);

    // Fecha Límite
    $fecha = new Text('fecha_final');
    $fecha->setLabel('Fecha Final');
    $fecha->addValidators(array(
        new PresenceOf(array(
            'message' => 'Por favor pon una fecha límite'
            ))
        ));
    $this->add($fecha);
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
<div class="page-header">
<h2>Registro de Nueva Keyword</h2>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<section class="container animated fadeInUp">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div id="login-wrapper">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">     
                    Registrar Nueva Keyword
                </h3>  
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ form('admin/nuevakeyword/', 'id': 'nuevakeywordForm', 'onbeforesubmit': 'return false') }}

                <fieldset>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('trackeable', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('trackeable', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('idcliente', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('idcliente', ['class': 'form-control']) }}                           
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        {{ form.label('fecha_final', ['class': 'control-label']) }}
                        <div id="datepicker" class="controls">
                            {{ form.render('fecha_final', ['class': 'form-control']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        {{ submit_button('Insertar', 'class': 'btn btn-primary', 'onclick': 'return SignUp.validate();') }}
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#fecha_final").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function nuevakeywordAction(){
    $auth = $this->session->get('auth');
    $permiso = $auth['active'];
    if($permiso!='A'){return $this->forward('servicios/index');}

    $form = new NuevakeywordForm;

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        $trackeable = $this->request->getPost('trackeable', array('string', 'striptags'));
        $idcliente = $this->request->getPost('idcliente');
        $fecha = $this->request->getPost('fecha');

        $keyword = new Keyword();
        $keyword->trackeable = $trackeable;
        $keyword->cliente_idcliente = $idcliente;
        $keyword->fecha_inicial = new Phalcon\Db\RawValue('now()');
        $keyword->fecha_final = $fecha;
        if ($keyword->save() == false) {
            foreach ($keyword->getMessages() as $message) {
                $this->flash->error((string) $message);
            }
        } else {
            $this->tag->setDefault('trackeable', '');
            $this->tag->setDefault('idcliente', '');
            $this->tag->setDefault('fecha', '');
            $this->flash->success('Keyword agregada correctamente');
            return $this->forward('admin/verkeywords');
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

I'm using MariaDB (the same as MySQL). I'm trying to find an "addValidator" for the date, but maybe is other the problem. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Your input field for your date has the name `fecha_final` but in your controller you use `fecha`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Date`

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/api/Phalcon_Validation_Validator_Date.html